# Using MongoDB API in a Web application

Tags: mongodb-java

I'd need to use the **MongoClient** and **DB** objects repeatedly in a Web application:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
```

Is it safe to cache and re-use these objects among different clients accessing our application? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create this once and inject it via CDI/Guice, if you can.  If you can't do that, you could use a static factory method to return the one instance of your `MongoClient`.  `MongoClient` maintains a connection pool and is safe to use between different threads.  If you create a new `MongoClient` with each request, not only is it going to be a performance hit to set up that pool and open a new connection, but you'll likely leave dangling connections unless you properly close that `MongoClient` at the end of the request.

Comment: Thanks from your reply. By means of CDI sounds nice for a Java EE environment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  [From Getting Started with Java Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/), "you will only need one instance of class MongoClient even with multiple threads".

As a side note, the Mongo Java driver is a pain to use. The dev team I'm part of is very happy with [Jongo](http://jongo.org/), a wrapper around the Java driver that allows queries to be written more like shell queries.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, sounds quite interesting!